# Google Sheets - How to Combine Filter Function with Filter View

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, show-hide, filterfunction, google-sheets-filter-view

I've been working on a spreadsheet with over 100 rows, and found a hacky way to incorporate a "hide" checkbox that will hide any row where column C matches a specific value (building type), specified beside the box. To do this, I first created a function like this: `=FILTER(Data!A1, OR(Data!$C1<>$O$2, $P$2))` and dragged that across every row and column in a seperate sheet. This reads as, "Display current cell if the corresponding column C in that row in Data does not match the building type, or if the the checkbox is checked. This way, the whole row is hidden when the building type matches, and the box is unchecked. A1 adjusted to each row individually, $C1 referenced the building's type, $O$2 referenced the targeted type to potentially hide, and $P$2 was the checkbox.

Problem #1: This created a lot of formulas in hundreds of cells, and when the building type was not found, it displayed #N/A across the entire row. A Filter View was able to hide these values, but it was inconvenient to have to reset the values every time I wanted to hide or unhide another building type.

My Attempt to Fix: I used a filter function once again to recreate the entire sheet from one cell, hiding the appropriate rows, using this: `=FILTER(Data!A2:J191, ARRAYFORMULA((Data!$C2:C191<>$O$2)+(Data!D2:D191*$P$2))` This is the hacky part. I multiplied the checkbox's "true" by an array arbitrary positive numerical values in the D column to "OR" it with each building type value to achieve the same goal as before, but for EVERY cell.

Problem #2 arose: When I get my beautiful sheet, I can not sort it via a filter view, or it will throw an error and display nothing. I'm resorting to sorting the original tab, but intend to have it be ignored entirely. So how do I combine these two, Filter View, and Filter Function, to create a nice spreadsheet where I can SORT AND HIDE rows?

Bonus Problem #3: To add more buttons, my formula is this: `=FILTER(Data!A1:J191, ARRAYFORMULA((Data!$C1:C191<>$O$2)+(Data!D2:D192*$P$2)), ARRAYFORMULA((Data!$C1:C191<>$O$3)+(Data!D2:D192*$P$3)), ARRAYFORMULA((Data!$C1:C191<>$O$4)+(Data!D2:D192*$P$4)), ARRAYFORMULA((Data!$C1:C191<>$O$5)+(Data!D2:D192*$P$5)), ARRAYFORMULA((Data!$C1:C191<>$O$6)+(Data!D2:D192*$P$6)), ARRAYFORMULA((Data!$C1:C191<>$O$7)+(Data!D2:D192*$P$7)), ARRAYFORMULA((Data!$C1:C191<>$O$8)+(Data!D2:D192*$P$8)), ARRAYFORMULA((Data!$C1:C191<>$O$9)+(Data!D2:D192*$P$9)))` This is ugly, and very slow to load. Is there a way to create a function range to handle the same checks on multiple rows, and crunch it into a single formula?

Comment: UPDATE: I found a way around this by adding a checkbox on the second row to handle sorting, making values on the checked boxes range from 1-11, and unchecked being 0, throwing a sort function around that monster function and adding A2, False, B2, False, etc. etc., but for the love of all that is digital, somebody needs to tell me how to make this more efficient.

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this site. Will a link to it work? I'll look into how to provide a sample. For now, here's a link. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10iKaDoV4cR7J05pxjn0pwjSbrvdi3Yi9Jm7pq9sQARw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another monstrosity (this one has less repetition) for you:

```
=QUERY(
  {IGNORE!A2:J, IGNORE!P2:P},
    "SELECT * "
  & "WHERE Col3 is not null "
  & IF(COUNTIF(P2:P9, False) = 0, "", "AND NOT Col3 MATCHES '^" & JOIN("$|^", IFNA(FILTER(O2:O9, P2:P9 = False))) & "$' ")
  & IF(COUNTIF(A2:K2, ">0") = 0, "", "ORDER BY Col" & JOIN(", Col", IFNA(FILTER(COLUMN(A2:K2) & IF(COLUMN(A2:K2) = 1, "", " DESC"), A2:K2)))),
  0
)
```

Your checkboxes should remain. The second row can have just True/False values, no need for column number (a simple change will be needed `COUNTIF(A2:K2, ">0")` -> `COUNTIF(A2:K2, True)`). Also consequent sort works now (but only in the actual order of columns: if checked 1, 3, 4 then it will be sorted first by 1, then by 2, then by 4). You could place another config table on the right about sorting, where you would select all the columns you wish to sort by, their mutual order, and desc/asc for them.

[image]

**Edit:** added `IFNA` so `FILTER` won't return an error, changed multiple `ANDS` to `MATCHES` and simple regexes.

Comment: Amazing! I had no idea about the query function. This is a much more manageable piece for extending types and rows. Exactly what I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BraxtonIstace fixed the solution a bit.

Comment: your previous solution appears to have worked, but when I try the updated version, it does not hide all of the rows that are supposed to be hidden. I'll have a look at the two and see what I can figure out in the mean time. Thanks for the effort you've put in!

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for slaying this monster. I wish I could offer more than an upvote, a checkmark, and my gratitude.